# Can symbolic sums of indexed arrays be simplified?

Tags: core-language, sum

As a simple example, is it possible to simplify say

```
Sum[Indexed[x, i], {i, 1, n}] == Indexed[x, n] + Sum[Indexed[x, i], {i, 1, n - 1}]
```

If not, please explain whether this should (or not) be possible. Thanks!

Comment: If your `n` were defined, then I would expect this to evaluate to True. If `n` isn't defined, then the `Sum` expressions will be just left incompletely evaluated. Thus, the equality cannot be determined just by the expression evaluation rules.